# minimum cardinality maximal matching of graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, approximation, matching, bipartite-matching

How to find minimum cardinality maximal matching?
I tried that pick a edge from highest degree vertex remove other edges from same vertex and so on.

Answer (score 2):

A 2-approximation can be obtained by returning a maximal matching, Call it M.
Let OPT be a minimum maximal matching then for each edge in M OPT covers at least one of its endpoints thus: |OPT|>=|M|/2
It would be better if you’ll be more explicit about what you did and what you’d like the algorithm to achieve (analysis of your idea, approximation factor, so on...)